# DNN 9.11.0 causing .js issues

Tags: javascript, dotnetnuke

I downloaded DNN 9.11.0 and noticed that non of my modules are working any longer. Upon further investigation I noticed that in versions DNN 9.10 jequry.js script tag used to be in header and mymodules.js script tag used to be in body right before mygopage.js tag another. So everything was working correctly.
But for some reason in DNN 9.11.0 mymodule.js script tag is showing up under header. This is causing errors with mygoPage.js as it needs to be before mymodule.js.
It looks like something was changed in Default.aspx page

```
<asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="ClientDependencyHeadJs"></asp:PlaceHolder>
```

I could not find this change information in release notes. Also can you help how can I solve this problem? I don't want to manually add script tags to hack the system. I want to solve this proper way.

I tried adding jquery.js script tag in header which resolved errors with my mygopage.js but then I started getting more errors with other .js files

Comment: Have you tried 9.11.1 or 9.11.2 to see if this is still an issue?

Comment: It is still an issue in 9.11.2. We can not upgrade as extension scripts are now loaded in the head instead of the body.